# Все нечетные столбцы заменить столбцом . (Нумерация столбцов массива начинается с нуля.) Реализация через функцию

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Не могу увидеть синтаксические ошибки в коде, если это они. Подскажите, пожалуйста

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T* createprintX(int cols, T c)
{
    T* X = new T[cols];
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)                                                      // Ввод и вывод строки X
        cin >> X[i];

    return X;
}

template<typename T>
T** create(int rows, int cols, T c)
{
    T** a = new T * [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        a[i] = new T[cols];
                                                                                       // Ввод двумерного массива
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
        {
            cout << "[ " << i << " ][ " << j << " ] = ";
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    return a;
}

template<typename T>
void print(int rows, int cols, T** a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)                                                  // Вывод двумерного массива
            cout << a[i][j] << '\t';

        cout << endl;
    }
}

template<typename T>
T** change(int rows, int cols, T** a, T* X)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {


        if (j % 2 != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                a[i][j] = X[i];
            }
        }

    }

    return a;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    cout << "Введите количество строк в двумерном массиве n = ";  int rows;  cin >> rows;
    cout << "Введите количество стобцов в двумерном массике m = ";  int cols;  cin >> cols;

    int type;
    cout << "\nДвумерный массив содержит :\n";
    cout << "1 - целые числа\n";
    cout << "2 - вещественные числа double\n";
    cout << "3 - вещественные числа float\n";
    cout << "Введите номер той строчки, которая нужны вам : ";
    cin >> type;

    cout << endl << endl;

    switch (type)
    {
        case(1): {

            int c = 1;
            cout << "int\n";

            int** a = create(rows, cols, c);
            cout << "\n\n=======================================\n\n";
            print(rows, cols, a);
            cout << "\n\n=======================================\n\n";
            cout << "\nВведите строку X:\n";
            int* X = createprintX(rows, c);
            cout << "\n\n=======================================\n\n";
            a = change(rows, cols, a, X);
            print(rows, cols, a);

            break;
        }

        case(2): {

            double c = 1;
            cout << "int\n";

            double** a = create(rows, cols, c);
            cout << "\n\n=======================================\n\n";
            print(rows, cols, a);
            cout << "\n\n=======================================\n\n";
            cout << "\nВведите строку X:\n";
            double* X = createprintX(rows, c);
            cout << "\n\n=======================================\n\n";
            a = change(rows, cols, a, X);
            print(rows, cols, a);

            break;
        }

        case(3): {

            float c = 1;
            cout << "int\n";

            float** a = create(rows, cols, c);
            cout << "\n\n=======================================\n\n";
            print(rows, cols, a);
            cout << "\n\n=======================================\n\n";
            cout << "\nВведите строку X:\n";
            float* X = createprintX(rows, c);
            cout << "\n\n=======================================\n\n";
            a = change(rows, cols, a, X);
            print(rows, cols, a);

            break;
        }

    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в чем ошибка то?

Comment: Да, я сам не знаю, код просто не запускается

Comment: Ну как это так? Я запустил у себя и мне сразу Visual Studio сказала, что в функции `createprintX` идентификатор `i` не найден. И правда его там нет, ведь там `j`

Comment: А, точно, я забыл в проект включить